# I just want to change my wordpress theme but the problem is with woocommerce . the site is live

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes, seo, e-commerce

I just want to change the theme of my wordpress ecommerce site. because the old developer who built this site used a lot of custom code and 45+ plugins. and as a result, the site speed is very slow (I am using a VPS server). and when I am trying to optimize the speed the custom js and css break the website
"note: I follow the all steps according to the documentation".
So, my objective is i want to deactivate the all custom js, css code and unusual plugins. On over i just want to change my theme which will help me to fulfill my all the needs. So please help me how to change the theme layout without losings the orders and content. and without affecting the customer order interruption
.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without deep knowledge of all the custom code that is in use on your website. There could be a number of issues depending on how that work was done. I suggest speaking to your host about creating a staging/development copy of your website where you can safely make changes without affecting your live site. With trial and error you might be able to get things working, but if there is a lot of custom functionality you will likely need a professional (just be aware than hiring is not allowed on this particular site).

Comment: ok. but i already chose the theme which fulfills my all feature. the problem does it afect my seo rank and customer order interruption